# Logging values of variable with kivy.logger

Tags: python, logging, kivy

I want to log the value of a variable using kivy.logger in file.

I added the following lines to my code:

```
from kivy.logger import Logger

Logger.debug('EZS-2G:  element: %s', str(element))
```

the following line appears in my IDE (Atom):

```
[DEBUG             ] [EZS-2G      ]  element: tab_0_obj_sensor
```

but the log file under C:\Users\username.kivy\logs says only:

```
[DEBUG             ] EZS-2G: %s
```

- How could I write the correct value into the logfile instead of %s?
- How could I change the folder of the log files? After the packaging (creating a "myapp/myapp.exe") I want to read the logs in the myapp/logs folder, instead of the "C:\Users\username.kivy\logs" folder?

OS: Win7 ; Python: 3.4 ; Kivy: 1.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- try `'EZS-2G:  element: {}'.format(element)`
- change `log_dir` in the config, check [Logger configuration](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.logger.html?highlight=logger#logger-configuration)